# Delta Lake in EMR

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-emr, delta-lake

I'm trying to use a delta lake through a python program that is called by a step on an EMR cluster, but the step always fails with an unknown error. I suppose the error could be related to the delta.tables import as the code is very simple.

**Python program: test.py**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Spark Session creation
spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaExercise")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .getOrCreate()
)

# Importing delta
from delta.tables import *


# Reading
enem = (
    spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("inferSchema", True)
    .option("header", True)
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .load("MyBucket/raw-data/microdados_enem_2020.csv")          
)

#Writing
(
    enem
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("delta")
    .partitionBy("year")
    .save("MyBucket/staging/test")
)
```

**Step in EMR cluster:**

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0 --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog --master yarn MYBUCKET/emr-code/pyspark/test.py
```

**EMR config screens:**
[image: Software Configuration]

If anyone has any tips on how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It was a mistake in the EMR cluster configuration. Delta files were created successfully.

Comment: Oh that's really good to hear!  BTW, don't hesitate to join us at https://go.delta.io/slack and ask your questions there (or point to your SO question there) to help get our attention, eh?!  HtH!

Comment: @DennyLee I'm not familiar with slack, I once tried using it and it asked to create a workspace. I gave up after that...lol... Anyway I'll try again.

Comment: best wishes - you can also join us at our Delta Lake [Google Groups](https://go.delta.io/groups) or [LinkedIn](https://go.delta.io/linkedin) if those are easier.  HTH!

Comment: Thanks @DennyLeeI, I'll join Google groups first and try Slack again asap.